# Prove that there is no function $g\in L^1[-1,1]$ such that $f(\phi)=\int_{-1}^1\phi g\,dx$ for all $\phi\in C[-1,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> For every $\phi \in C[-1,1]$ define the bounded linear functional 
>   $$f(\phi)=\phi(0).$$
>   Prove that there is no function $g\in L^1[-1,1]$ such that
>   $$ f(\phi) = \int_{-1}^{1} \phi g \, \mathrm{d}x, \qquad \forall \, \phi\in C[-1,1]. $$

I verified that it is of course a bounded function. But to prove the result I used several test functions as $\phi$ but was not successful.

What I was trying to do is that: Since $g \in L^1$, it implies $\int_{-1}^{1} |g| <\infty$. So I thought of getting an expression like $n\leq\int|g|$ by choosing appropriate $\phi_n$ but I couldn't make it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delta function is not in $ L^1(\mathbb{R})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2574199/delta-function-is-not-in-l1-mathbbr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\phi_n(x)=1-n|x|$ for $|x| \leq \frac  1n$ and $\phi_n(x)=0$ for $|x|>\frac 1 n$. Then we get $1=\phi_n(0)=\int \phi_n(x) g(x)dx$. Use DCT to show that RHS tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. This contradiction proves that there is no such $g$.

Note: $\phi_n(x) \to 0$ for every $x \neq 0$ and $0\leq \phi_n(x) \leq 1$ for all $x$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just to make sure... for the Dominated Convergence theorem we can use $|g|$ as the dominating function right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.